# How to do vectorized conditional math with xarray to bin data

Tags: python, math, conditional-statements, vectorization, python-xarray

I have seen this type of question before, and I think I'm apply the right approach to doing conditional math with xarray.

I have a program which is going to bin wind directions into 1 of 16 bins. I can do this dataframes but not with xarray in an vectorized statement.  To bin wind direction into 16 bins, I do a conversion on any wind data greater than 348.75 degrees as: wind_dir = mywind_dir - 360.

The corrected wind directions are stored in the dataframe df['dir'].

So my test point 350 becomes -10, and the other 3 data points are unchanged.

below is my code to do this, followed by an attempt to do with xarray.

With my approach I get the error (which I expected):

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

but by what I read this is the right approach. New to xarray and hoping that someone can advise a better and working method to do conditional math replacement on xarray variables.

Thank you for any help, before hand. Josh

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import xarray as xr

# Will use this function later for xarray question
def angel_correction(x):
    cutoff = 348.75

    x = xr.where(cutoff <= x <= 360, x-360, x)
    return x

#create test wind speed and directions and time for four points
base = datetime(2022, 3, 25)
time = np.array([base + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(4)])

d = {"wind_spd": [10, 20, 30, 40], "wind_dir": [120, 350, 80, 170], "time" : time}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# now bin the data with all data between 348.5N and 11.5 North in top bin
# create 16 bins in total
nbins = 16
cutoff = 360 - (180 / nbins) # cutoff = 348.75
wd = 'wind_dir'
wind_corrected = np.zeros(len(df[wd]))
#
for i in range(len(df[wd])):
    print(df[wd][i])
    if cutoff <= df[wd][i] <= 360:
        wind_corrected[i] = df[wd][i] - 360
    else:
        wind_corrected[i] = df[wd][i]

df['dir'] = wind_corrected  # contains after correction 120, -10, 80, 170

#now create a test xarray dataset

now = datetime.now() # current date and time
date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

data_vars = {'wd':(['time'], df['wind_spd'],
                         {'units': 'mph',
                          'long_name':'miles per hour'}),
             'wd':(['time'], df['wind_dir'],
                         {'units':'degN',
                          'long_name':'Degrees from North'})}
coords = {'time': (['time'],time)}

# define global attributes

attrs = {'creation_date':date_time}
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=data_vars,
                coords=coords,
                attrs=attrs)
print(ds.info())

# now do binning with xarray instead of dataframe

corrected_angle = angel_correction(ds['wd'])
ds['corrected_angle'] = corrected_angle

print('finished, thank you')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual, I had an easy fix. I think I reading the documentation wrong. here's the fix in the code, first don't use any function or xr.where just do as follows:

```
# now do binning with xarray instead of dataframe

#correct_ang = angel_correction(ds['wd'])

ds['correct_ang'] = ds['wd']
ds['correct_ang'] = ds['correct_ang'].where(ds.correct_ang > 348.75, ds.correct_ang - 360.0)
```

print(ds.info())

Comment: Note, I never have wind directions greater than 360.0 so my last if statement was made more simple, and in my function I was using xr.where, vice here where I used ds['correct_ang'].where